# How to show the route line between two points on Google Distance Matrix service example

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm testing with the mapping example at

[Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix#try-it-yourself)

Is there a parameter to show the line between the two markers for the route.

Answer (score 0):

The [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/distance-matrix) computes distances and durations for multiple origin/destination pairs, it doesn't return the route.

If you need the route, use the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/directions).